# d3 charts throw unexplainable errors

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm creating some charts with ajax calls. Most of them work just fine, but some don't and throw errors.

I create the data like this:

```
function buybox() {                                                                                                                     
                                                                                                                                        
    var cust_price = [],                                                                                                                
        buy_price = [];                                                                                                                 
    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {                                                                                             
        cust_price.push({x: parseInt(data[i].ssc) + '000', y: (isNaN(parseFloat(data[i].cust))) ? 0.00 : parseFloat(data[i].cust)});    
        buy_price.push({x: parseInt(data[i].ssc) + '000', y: (isNaN(parseFloat(data[i].buy))) ? 0.00 : parseFloat(data[i].buy)});       
    }                                                                                                                                   
                                                                                                                                        
                                                                                                                                        
    return [                                                                                                                            
        {                                                                                                                               
            area: true,                                                                                                                 
            values: cust_price,                                                                                                         
            key: "Mein Preis",                                                                                                          
            color: "#81d4fa"                                                                                                            
        },                                                                                                                              
        {                                                                                                                               
            area: true,                                                                                                                 
            values: buy_price,                                                                                                          
            key: "Buybox Preis",                                                                                                        
            color: "#7cb342"                                                                                                            
        }                                                                                                                               
                                                                                                                                        
    ];                                                                                                                                  
}
```

The errors thrown are (only one error per chart):

> TypeError: vb is null d3charts.js:5194:25
>
> TypeError: d is undefined d3charts.js:20665:0

This is the corresponding d3 code:

For error vb is null:

```
  function d3_geom_voronoiHalfEdge(edge, lSite, rSite) {
    var va = edge.a, vb = edge.b;
    this.edge = edge;
    this.site = lSite;
 /* error in this line */   this.angle = rSite ? Math.atan2(rSite.y - lSite.y, rSite.x - lSite.x) : edge.l === lSite ? Math.atan2(vb.x - va.x, va.y - vb.y) : Math.atan2(va.x - vb.x, vb.y - va.y);
  }
```

For error d is undefined:

```
      var pointPaths = wrap.select('.nv-point-paths').selectAll('path')
          .data(voronoi);
      pointPaths.enter().append('path')
          .attr('class', function(d,i) { return 'nv-path-'+i; });
      pointPaths.exit().remove();
      pointPaths
          .attr('d', function(d) {
     /* error in this line */       if (d.data.length === 0)
                return 'M 0 0'
            else
                return 'M' + d.data.join('L') + 'Z';
          });
```

data.ssc is a timestamp and data.buy/data.cust are prices.

If error vb occurs, the graph looks like this:

[image]

If error d occurs, the graph looks like this (which looks totally ok):

[image]

And this is how they look if there is no error:

[image]

(All those graphs come with different data, so don't mind the different views)

The charts are rendered like they should, no matter which of above errors occure, but if there's an error, the tooltip doesn't work. Here's the tooltip generator:

```
        chart2.tooltipContent(function (key, y, e, graph) {
            var date = new Date(parseInt(graph.point.x));
            var day = date.getDate();
            var month = date.getMonth() + 1;
            var hours = date.getHours();
            var minutes = "0" + date.getMinutes();
            var formattedTime = day + '.' + month + '. - ' + hours + ':' + minutes.substr(minutes.length-2);
            return '<div class="text-center" style="padding:10px;"><span class="text-center"><strong>' + key + '</strong></span><br><span class="text-center">' + formattedTime + '</span><br><span class="text-center"><strong>' + e + ' €</strong></span></div>'
        })
```

Does somebody have a clue on how to fix this?